# ¿Como mantener un proceso de la CMD abierta para mandarle comandos desde C#?

Tags: c#, cmd, terminal

Me podrían orientar a realizar lo siguiente si no les causa molestia:
Estoy haciendo un **Editor de C++ en C#**, pero estoy buscando la forma de que este pueda compilar el código de C++ por medio de g++ desde la CMD, pero hasta ahorita lo que he investigado no me ha ayudado mucho, hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo:

Esta parte del código es el proceso de compilación de un archivo ya que necesito generar el **.EXE**, **.O** y **.S** si se dan cuenta `ExecuteCommand();` es para ingresar el comando

```
private void MemoriaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * Ahora para compilar en memoria tenemos que llevar a cabo el siguiente proceso, primeramente para que el 
         * codigo fuente pueda ser compilado necesita guardarse en un archivo con la extension .cpp, sabiendo que 
         * el codigo fue creado en nuestro programa ya que para eso esta la otra opcion de compilacion en disco, es asi
         * que en este proceso es lo que se necesita para poder compilar.
         */
         if(Direccion_archivo==null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El Archivo no ha sido guardado, por favor hagalo antes de compilar");
        }
         else
        {
            //empieza el proceso de compilacion
            //Generamos 3 archivos
            // -> .exe  "Ejecutable"
            // -> .o    "Codigo objeto"
            // -> .s    "Codigo Ensamblador"
            ExecuteCommand("cd " + Dir_raiz);
            //Terminal.ClearSelected();
            ExecuteCommand("g++ -v " + Direccion_archivo + " -o " + Direccion_archivo.Replace(".cpp", ".exe"));
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            ExecuteCommand("g++ -v " + Direccion_archivo + " -o " + Direccion_archivo.Replace(".cpp", ".o"));
            //Generamos el codigo Ensamblador Resultado de el siguiente comando
            ExecuteCommand("g++ -S -masm=intel " + Direccion_archivo);
            codigo_asm = File.ReadAllText(Direccion_archivo.Replace(".cpp", ".s"));
            Salida_Assembler.Clear();
            Salida_Assembler.Text = codigo_asm;
            flag_execute = true;
        }
    }
```

En esta parte de aquí esta el método para ejecutar los comandos de CMD, debido a que soy algo inexperto en el uso de la CMD implementada a un lenguaje investigue a un poco y encontré las rutinas contenidas en esta función del Blog de **Code Tricks**, pero el problema es que abre una nueva consola cada vez que yo implemento la función `ExecuteCommand()` y después de revisar muchas veces no es capaz de generar ningún archivo de compilación por ningún, pienso que debería de implementar un hilo para que la consola se mantenga abierta y pasar los comandos pero debido a que desconozco sobre el tema y he investigado pero no he encontrado mucha información al respecto; podrían ayudarme a implementar una solución a este problema.

```
private void ExecuteCommand(String _Command)
    {
        /*
         * Lo que necesitamos es hacer uso de la cmd para poder compilar el codigo que nosostros pongamos en el 
         * editor de texto, pero antes que nada debemos de tener instalado el compilador en este caso como vamos a 
         * utilizar c++ y c como  lenguaje base para compilar estamos obligados a utilizar Gcc pero ya que este solo
         * esta disponible a traves de MinGW haremos uso de este programa y tambien por problemas de Compatibilidad 
         * en la arquitectura x86_64 haremos uso de Posix rev para tener compatibilidad en la arquitectura en la que 
         * estamos trabajando.
         */
        Process cmdProcess = null;
        cmdProcess = new Process();
        // Dump all info from ipconfig command
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/ALL";
        // Run command: ipconfig
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = _Command;
        // Redirect stdout
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        // Set to false, otherwise you can't redirect stdout
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Start process
        if (cmdProcess.Start())
        {
            // Read stdout and show the content in a rtf-box
            Terminal.Text = cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            // Failed to execute command
        }

    }
```

**Les agradecería bastante su ayuda**

**PD:** Los comandos para compilar de GCC no me han dado ningún problema en el CMD, cabe resaltar que los he estado probando sin ningún problema desde la consola, a su vez estoy usando **MinGW** como compilador.

Comment: Has pensado en crear un archivo .bat con todos los comandos, y ejecutar dicho archivo en lugar de los comandos uno a uno?

Comment: @Pikoh Muchas gracias por responder, creo que me has dado una idea muy buena, que voy a probar. Es lo siguiente: voy a crear un **archivo.bat** desde C# al momento de que yo guarde los archivos para compilar ya solo ejecute el .bat. En un rato actualizo el post.

Comment: Saludos @Krasnax, por curiosidad, ¿lograste solucionar el problema?

Comment: @fredyfx Si lo logre resolver, deja subo la solución

Comment: Muy agradecido, le darás una ayuda muchos más usuarios :D recuerda aceptar la respuesta para colabora con la salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de un buen tiempo, y al no obtener una respuesta acerca de la solución, yo mismo pude diseñar una solución convincente a mi problema y totalmente funcional, para lo que necesitaba, en la cual es bastante sencilla.

```
        private void CrearDemonio(string _Direccion)
    {
        /* Salida del Archivo: 'demonio.bat'
         * Esta es una propuesta definitiva que dentro del proceso de desarrollo tendra una mejora, respecto a lo que concierne 
         * con la creacion de este archivo es de bastante importancia ya que en la version 1.27.8 alpha la creacion de una entrada
         * de comandos por medio de de un Process.Start(), daba bastantes problemas para ejecutar los comandos de compilación, pero 
         * ahora lo que tenemos que hacer es por medio de archivos por lotes de windows podemos hacer la compilacion esperando que 
         * que se generen los siguientes archivos:
         * -> .o    "Codigo Objeto"
         * -> .exe  "Archivo Ejecutable"
         * -> .s    "Codigo Assembly"
         * 
         * De esta forma si guardamos este con el nombre demonio.bat lo podemos ejecutar sin ningún problema en un solo proceso, pero 
         * se presenta otro problema que es no poder captar los errores que el compilador puede arrojarnos, lo que si puede hacer es
         * detener este proceso de manera autonoma ya si el primer paso de compilacion no se completa este automaticamente termina el 
         * proceso y ya no realiza toda la compilacion y no genera los archivos.
         */
        Text_demon= "g++ "+_Direccion+" -o "+_Direccion.Replace(".cpp",".o")+" && g++ "+_Direccion+" -o "+_Direccion.Replace(".cpp",".exe")+" && cd "+Dir_raiz+" && g++ -S -masm=intel "+_Direccion;
        //Guardamos el Demonio.
        File.WriteAllText(Dir_demon, Text_demon);
    }
```

Este es el proceso que me ayuda a compilar el programa, de hecho la idea es simple, a lo que es tener un archivo **.bat** llamado **Demonio.bat** almacenado en la carpeta donde esta almacenado el programa y lo que hace simplemente esta función es cambiar cambiar las extensiones del programa que tengo abierto en el programa y previamente ya guarde o sobrescribí y por medio de la función `Replace()` podemos cambiar las extensiones del archivo que vamos a compilar ya que necesitamos el ejecutable, el código objeto y el código ensamblador del programa.

Previamente para esto debemos de tener la dirección del archivo **Demonio.bat** en la cual yo la tengo almacenada en la variable tipo string `Dir_demon`.

Ahora para poder ejecutar este proceso simplemente lo llamamos e ingresamos el argumento, que en este caso es la dirección en donde esta guardada el programa que vamos a compilar en este caso tengo la dirección al igual la tengo almacenada en una variable llamada  `Direccion_Disk` y para ejecutar el proceso de `CrearDemonio()` es así:

```
CrearDemonio(@Direccion_Disk);
```

Y por ultimo para poder ejecutar el archivo por lotes que modificamos en tiempo de ejecución del programa nos ayudamos a través de un script en **Visual Basic** que este nos ayuda a mantener oculta la consola y la ejecuta en segundo plano.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Direccion en donde esta el archivo Demonio.bat" & Chr(34),0
  Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Por ultimo en el programa ya solo nosotros mandamos a llamar por medio de la siguiente función:

```
Process.Start(Dir_demon.Replace("demonio.bat","oculta.vbs"));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Dormimos el programa un pequeño periodo de tiempo debido a que el compilador tarda un poco en llevar a cabo los procesos de código objeto, código asm y el ejecutable.
Cabe resaltar que el script esta en la misma carpeta que en archivo por lotes por eso uso la función `Replace()`.

Bueno en fin esta es la solución que me sirvió bastante a mi y hasta la fecha sigue funcionando y no me ha dado ningún problema, espero que les sirva o les pueda dar alguna idea sobre como solucionar un problema parecido, Saludos.